# Connection too unix socket with c#

Tags: c#, sockets, unix-socket

I am trying to connect to a Unix Socket with C#. I have a console application that is using .NET Framework 4.8 and I depend on that version since i have to use System.Windows.Automation and some other libraries from .NET Framework 4.8.

The Console Application should connect to a socket from a node.js application opened with node ipc.

I seems that it is not possible to use UnixSocket with .NET Framework.
I tried the following

```
using System.Net.Sockets;

var unixSocketName = "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock";
var unixSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
unixSocket.Connect(new UnixDomainSocketEndPoint(unixSocketName));
```

But `UnixDomainSocketEndPoint` does not exist in .NET Framework. Is there any possibility I can make this work by import the .NET core Library?

Comment: .NET Core is not a library, it's an entirely different Framework and Runtime. If this is a new or even relatively modern project, I highly suggest you switch to using .NET 6 (which is actually a .NET Core version). .NET Framework doesn't run (natively) on anything that's not Windows, so there is also no support for Unix sockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UnixDomainSocketEndPoint` just applied from `.NET Standard 2.1` or `.NET Core 2.1`, which excluded `.NET Framework 4.8`.

> Is there any possibility I can make this work by import the .NET core Library?

Probably you need to switch the .NET platform to from `.NET Standard 2.1` or `.NET Core 2.1`

Comment: As I wrote in my Question. I depend on .NET Framework. Hence my question is how to make it work with .NET Framework.

Comment: If OP is creating a console application, then .NET Standard (any version) is out of the question, as it can't compile to an executable program, only to a library. Plus, don't switch to .NET Core 2.1, it's unsupported (it's official end of support was Aug 21, 2021), instead use .NET 6. Not only is it much newer and has way more .NET Framework APIs, it's also faster and backwards compatible

Comment: @Silve2611 then the answer "you can't"

Comment: In .NET 6.0 i am missing System.Windows.Automation. Can it be added. Afaik it should be available